# Importing test coverage results into WebStorm

Tags: gulp, webstorm, karma-coverage

I have pretty complicated testing infrastructure that I scaffold before the test using `gulp` runner thus I can't use the build in debugger for unit tests in WebStorm v10.0.0.

During the test execution I generate the test coverage using `karma-coverage` that lands into reports/unit-test-coverage file.

**Question:** Can I import this file into WebStorm to see the coverage for my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to load coverage reports into IDE. Please follow [WEB-10303](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10303)